# Reference to ASP.NET C# assemblies when use Identity and OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin, .net-4.5.2

In a Visual Studio Website or Solution, is it possible to reference to multiple internal/external project child assemblies (DLLs) each made using its own Identity, OWIN, Startup.cs and each connected to different database or same database using different database prefix (APR_ letters instead of AspNet name)?